# Поиск из пунктов

Tags: javascript, css, html5, placeholder

Имеется выпадашка, в которой содержаться пункты с названиями городов, а также placeholder. Суть идеи такова, что когда пишешь в placeholdere название города, Например Санкт-Петербург, нужно чтобы все остальные пункты(с другими городами отсеивались, и оставался только Питер. Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: что в вашем понимании "placeholder"?

Comment: Это просто область, где человек пишет текст.

Comment: @DaniilLav  placeholder это место где идет подсказка что должен пользователь писать в поле, а пользователь пишет в инпут

Comment: Daniil Lav, placeholder - подсказка для поля ввода, то что вы описали - это поле ввода (input, textarea), то что в него ввели - значение (value) поля ввода.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно обойтись простым HTML5: `<input />` + `<datalist>`.

```html
<label>Choose a browser from this list:
<input list="browsers" name="myBrowser" /></label>
<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
  <option value="Microsoft Edge">
</datalist>
```

Источник: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам простейший способ выборки по вводу в инпут. Не понятно какая у вас структура "выпадашки", так что дальше вам придеться самому.

```js
const inputCities = [
    { name: "Piter" },
    { name: "Moscow" },
    { name: "Minsk" },
    { name: "Paris" },
    { name: "Monako" },
]
let cities = []

const input = document.querySelector('input');
input.oninput = () => {
    cities = inputCities;
    cities = cities.filter(c => c.name.startsWith(input.value))
    console.log(cities)
}
```

```html
<input/>
```

Comment: Штука хорошая исходя из скупости вводных. Но я бы скорее посоветовал использовать готовые библиотеки которые ищут не только точные совпадения от начала строки, то есть так же что бы находило Санкт-Петербург по запросу "пет" (или, боже упаси, "питер")

Comment: А вы можете посоветовать такие библиотеки пожалуйста ? Я был бы благодарен.